# How to upload and view excel sheet using office 365 in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, office365

How to upload, view and edit excel sheet using office 365 in asp.net.

Need help!! 
Please.Got deadline from company to do it in 1 day. Need help

I don't found any good document.

Any help, How to upload, view and edit excel sheet using Sharepoint using asp.net.

Comment: Your company may have given you a deadline to do it in one day, but that is not our problem. Your question is too broad, you're basically asking us to write the code for you. We're not a free code writing service. You need to pay people if you expect them to do your work for you. I suggest you make your own attempt at solving the problem. Then if you have a specific problem with your implementation, that would be a more appropriate question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: You may want to set some different expectations for this project.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with mason. Here's a couple of pointers for you.

Here's an example of accessing [O365 from an ASP.NET web app](https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-ASPNETMVC-Start). For an example of how to upload from your web application to O365, you can checkout the [upload code in this example](https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-Windows-Start).